# Simple Java app (3 buttons - every of them starts and stops a count)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm learning Java (I code some in C++). I just wanted to create an APP with threads. As I know, I can't use a thread to manipulate UI (MainThread).

This app would look like this: Draw 3 buttons, draw 3 textboxes.
When I click button 1, the counting starts in TextView 1 (from 1 to inf). Second and third are the same. I need to make three threads, but I can't understand, how to manipulate the UI (update the textview with new number). I've also heard about AsyncTask, but I think it's not for apps like this (read that this is for connecting/downloading etc).

Could some of you explain how to solve this? I don't need any code, just an explanation - what would be the best way to write this :)

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the text and buttons, you can add TextViews and Buttons in **activity_main.xml** file.

For each Button, set a method, maybe startCounting(View view), to be done when the Button is clicked. In that method, add a Handler:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
final int DELAY = 1000; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //Increase textview number by one here
        h.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
    }
}, DELAY);
```

No AsyncTask is required.

Here is a simple version of the app you are trying to build:

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;

int time1 = 0;
int time2 = 0;
int time3 = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    b1    = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2    = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3    = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
}

public void startFirstTimer(View v){
    time1 = 0;

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int DELAY = 1000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            time1++;
            tv1.setText(Integer.toString(time1));
            h.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
        }
    }, DELAY);
}
public void startSecondTimer(View view){
    time2 = 0;

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int DELAY = 1000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            time2++;
            tv2.setText(Integer.toString(time2));
            h.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
        }
    }, DELAY);
}
public void startThirdTimer(View view){
    time3 = 0;

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int DELAY = 1000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            time3++;
            tv3.setText(Integer.toString(time3));
            h.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
        }
    }, DELAY);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start First Timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:onClick="startFirstTimer"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Second Timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
    android:onClick="startSecondTimer"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Third Timer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
    android:onClick="startThirdTimer"/>
```

Comment: @Insane You are welcome. Make sure that when the application is closed, the loop stops. Otherwise, it will run constantly.